# NextJS build command hangs indefinitely on our server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs

I'm having a problem when running `next build` on my local machine (Windows 10) the command builds the app successfully
But when doing so on my server (running on `linux 4.18.0-372.9.1.1.lve.el8.x86_64` the build hangs indefinitely, this was tested on my current project, I've also tried testing on a new project created on the linux server and got the same issue

[image: Running next build on Linux machine]

I tried skipping linting and type checks from `next.config.js` but it still hangs

[image: Running next build and skipping linting and type checks]

I noticed this process running while the app is "building", might be the source of the issue but I'm not sure

[image: ---]

I might also be missing some dependencies that I am not aware of, any ideas?

### Edit (1)

```js
// next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    distDir: "./build",
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "http",
                hostname: "localhost",
                port: "1337",
                pathname: "/uploads/**",
            },
            {
                protocol: "http",
                hostname: "127.0.0.1",
                port: "1337",
                pathname: "/uploads/**",
            },
        ],
    },
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/news",
                destination: "/",
                permanent: false,
            },
        ];
    },
};

const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig);
```

### Edit (2)

While the app is building, the cpu usage shoots between 92% and 100%, without building it rests at 14%

[image: CPU usage while building]

Is there a way to bypass running tests with jest while building?

Comment: Why is it loading production env from .env.local? 
Also, are you using webpack? It would be helpful to see your next config.

Comment: Please first clear the cache by npm cache clean --force then try once again.

Comment: @AbhayShiro updated with the next config file

Comment: @NaeemAhmed just ran a forced cache clean but the issue still persists

Comment: @IbrahimA.Elaradi Please remove .lock file and also node_modules then try to reinstall and build.

Comment: @NaeemAhmed just tried that but it didn't solve the issue, I've edited the post to add more info that might cause this issue, please check edit (2)